# How can I get the number of hits of a query in a search engine in Java/JavaScript?

Tags: search-engine-api

I need to find the number of hits that query gets in a web search engine (such as Google) in a specific domain. For instance, if the user searches '"dry martini recipe" site:.uk', Google shows "About 15,800 results". I need to get that number (15,800).

The Google API used to be able to do this, but now is deprecated. I have considered web scraping, but since it is not allowed, I would rather not go this way. Using Google is in no way a must, I have considered engines like Duck Duck Go, but the web results do not seem to include the total count of this of a query.

Comment: So if you Google [`"dry martini recipes" site:.uk`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dry+martini+recipes%22+site%3A.uk), the resulting page shows `About 14,500 results` at the top of the list. Is your question really just how to get that number (14500), and is not in any way about `site:` queries? If so, why muddle the point with all that talk about irrelevant stuff? Ask the question: *"How do I get hit count?"* --- Edit the question and clarify what you're asking, without any irrelevant fluff.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback! I have just updated the query to make it clear. Please let me know if you think that it coulb be further improved.

Comment: Google and Yahoo both mention the number of hits, but to get it, first I need to accept the consent of cookies. So not possible to get the hits with something like wget or curl. Any ideas?

Comment: Answer my own question: I tried ask.com and here I can use curl, no redirect to a consent page or such.